# Java - Is this way of designing acceptable?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, project

Well, I'm doing a mini-project on Employee Management System. In my project, there is a base class named Person and another class Employee(which inherits Person). Now, I want to create a new class named Salary or Payroll which'll contain methods to calculate the salary of the employees.

The thing is that since there is no IS-A relationship between Salary and Employee, Salary can't be derived from Employee. I've two questions:

**1.** Is it possible to have a HAS-A relationship between Salary and Employee(Salary or Payroll has employees)?

**2.** I need to have Threads in my project. Kindly suggest me where can I implement it.

Cheers!

Comment: The threads part is completely irrelevant to the rest of your question and is also totally unclear why you need them for.

Comment: Thank you everybody! Successfully completed my mini-project and submitted it. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Has-A` is in the form of a field.

```
class Employee {
   private Salary mySalary;
}

class Salary { }
```

Your second question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a HAS-A relationship between Salary and Employee(Salary or Payroll has employees)?

Yes you can have. Just need to declare an association between Salary and Employee classes.

```
class Employee{
   private Salary salary;
   public Employee(Salary s){
       …………….
       …………….
       …………….
   }
}
```

---

> I need to have Threads in my project. Kindly suggest me where can I implement it.

You need to be more specific for this question. Why you need it and where?

> We have been told that our project must have the Multithreading concept implemented. I've no idea what to do.

Then i would say you can use multithreading in a scenario where suppose you want to calculate the salaries of all the employees. Then you can divide the employees to multiple threads and calculate simultaneously for faster turn around time. It just a thought for impress your professor. :)

Comment: We have been told that our project must have the Multithreading concept implemented. I've no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you **think** about it, it makes sense to say that an Employee has Salary, not the other way around. So yes, HAS-A relationship could be done in the form:

```
public class Employee {
    private Salary mSalary;
}
```

where

```
public class Salary {
    private float mAmount;
    //etc.
}
```

2.What exactly is the requirement?

**EDIT:**

Multithreading is a vast and complicated topic, there are books written on the subject. To start, please check out some tutorials, such as [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) or [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html)

Comment: We have been told that our project must have the Multithreading concept implemented. I've no idea what to do. :|